# Is it possible to load and run APK file inside Android Apps programmatically?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

in `App A`, i have UI Box. Is it possible to load `App B` (APK) then load and run it into the UI Box ?

so, its like run `App B` with frame from `App A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is not possible to install another application from one application as android made a sandbox for each application and prevent it from touching to other applications.

> NOTE: you can invoke an android package installer via Intent.

```
File apkFullPath = getFileStreamPath("name_of_downloaded_app.apk");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFullPath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this will help and solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run an apk without instsalling it first. What you can do is start intent for installing it and then use it as you wish.

Read this ans to start intent for installing an apk:

[Install apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/10290109)